# Custom metric for a Windows process on a Windows ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a process (exe) on a Windows ec2 that is using up lots of memory. I would like to create a custom metric that will collect data and send to CloudWatch. I would like to also create an alarm when a certain threshold has been reached or surpassed.

Answer (score 1):

Memory consumption is a metric that has to be reported from inside the guest (EC2 instance).  You can [use a CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to collect metrics from the guest directly. The agent also [supports custom metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-adds-custom-metrics-support/) now.

Alternatively, install a third party monitoring system. Which also means that you'll have to get an agent running on the EC2 instance. There are many of those, choose whatever fits your environment.

Comment: Thank you bgdnlp. Sorry, I should elaborated as what I have already attempted. I have created the necessary role and attached all the correct policies:

Get_from_param_store
ssm_put_parameter_only
AmazonEC2RoleforSSM
CloudWatchAgentAdminPolicy
CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy
AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore

I have also installed the cloudwatch agent and configured two config files:

procstat config and statd config. Not sure why it is not sending the memory consumption for that process to CloudWatch.